# Spring MVC :URI not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

**I am using the below URL to send a request,but i am getting a 404 error.
with a warning on server:No mapping found for HTTP request with URI**

The URI is

http://localhost:8080/webstore/products/tablet/price;low=200;high=400?manufacturer="Google"

The method in controller used is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/products/{category}/{ByCriteria}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSpecificProductByFilter(@PathVariable("category")String ProductCategory,@MatrixVariable(pathVar= "ByCriteria") Map<String,List<Long>> filterParams,@RequestParam String manufacturer,Model model){
    model.addAttribute("products",productService.getfilterproducts(ProductCategory,filterParams, manufacturer));
    return "products";
}
```

The category  signifies "tablet"in the URI

Criteria signifies"low" and "high"

manufacturer is"google"

Comment: Your mapping if for `/product/...`, but your actual path is `/products/...`. This `s` here won't be magically ignored by Spring.

Comment: @JBNizet I have changed the path accordingly but i am  facing the same problem which i was facing earlier

Comment: can you post web.xml ?

Comment: I have tried in similar way everything is working fine for me. there might be other issue

Answer (score 1):

For those who dont know, this is from book "Spring MVC begginers guide" by Amuthan G. This question is really old but I will give there my solution just in case somebody going to need that, just like me today.

First of all your @RequestMapping is wrong. It should looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{category}/{ByCriteria}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

And reason for that is you already have `@RequestMapping("/products")` on this whole controller class (above your class declaration). And because you want to map 
`webstore/products/tablet` and **NOT** `webstore/products/products/tablet` you have to **leave** that "products" mapping from this method.

Second thing is your URI. I know that in the books there is this one and its not really big deal, but if you dont want to have problems, **leave** quotation marks next to word Google. Its because you dont want to have value "Google" but just Google without these quation marks and if you let them there, you will have problems with comparing values. So your URI should looks like this.

http://localhost:8080/webstore/products/tablet/price;low=200;high=400?manufacturer=Google

For complete solution you have to do following steps:

1. In your repository and service interfaces and classes write method:

   `List<Product> getProductsByManufacturer(String manufacturer);`

   and implement it in same way like you wrote method `GetProductsByCategory`.
2. In your repository and service interfaces and classes write method:

   `Set<Product> getProductsByPrice(Map<String, List<String>> priceParams);`

   and implement it in same way like you wrote method `getProductsByFilter`.
3. Finnaly write method in Controller class:

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/{category}/{ByPrice}")
   public String filterProducts(@PathVariable("category") String productCategory,
           @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "ByPrice") Map<String, List<String>> filterParams,
           @RequestParam String manufacturer, Model model) {
       List<Product> byCategory = productService.getProductsByCategory(productCategory);
       List<Product> byManufacturer = productService.getProductsByManufacturer(manufacturer);
       Set<Product> byPrice = productService.getProductsByPrice(filterParams);
       byCategory.retainAll(byManufacturer);
       byCategory.retainAll(byPrice);
       model.addAttribute("products", byCategory);
       return "products";
   }
   ```

   In my project this method look like this, but you can certainly do it in shorter way. After you complete these steps, your project should working. If not, feel free to ask me there. If you dont know how to write methods in steps 1 and 2 I will comment there code for you, but its almost same like that another methods as I said. I hope that this is going to help somebody.

Comment: I am reading the same book, and I would like to thank you for your help!